# How to draw a number above a circle on tikz picture?

Tags: graph, latex, tikz

I am using tikz package to draw a graph and I need to know how to insert a number above the circle to indicate the order of each one on the graph.
Here's what I get so far:

```
(1, 4) node[circle, black, draw](a){A}
(2.5, 4) node[circle, black, draw](b){B}
(4, 4) node[circle, black, draw](c){C}
(1, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw](d){D}
(2.5, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw](e){E}
(4, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw](f){F}
(1, 1) node[circle, black, draw](g){G}
(2.5, 1) node[circle, black, draw](h){H}
(4, 1) node[circle, black, draw](i){I};
```

What I want is to identify the node A is the first, B the second, C the third... until the last one, by adding a number above its circle.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for the label is `label=[position]:[label_text]`:

```
node[circle, black, draw, label=left:1](a){A}
(2.5, 4) node[circle, black, draw, label=above:2](b){B}
(4, 4) node[circle, black, draw, label=right:3](c){C}
(1, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw, label=below:4](d){D}
(2.5, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw, label=5](e){E}
(4, 2.5) node[circle, black, draw, label=6](f){F}
(1, 1) node[circle, black, draw, label=7](g){G}
(2.5, 1) node[circle, black, draw, label=8](h){H}
(4, 1) node[circle, black, draw, label=9](i){I};
```

[image]